# list of random integers without zero Python

Tags: python, xrange

I need a random list of integers without 0. I'm using `random.sample(xrange(y),z)` but I don't want 0 in this list. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your range at 1 then:

```
random.sample(xrange(1, y), z)
```

That's all there is to it, really.

Demo:

```
>>> list(xrange(3))
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(xrange(1, 3))
[1, 2]
```

`xrange()` doesn't just produce a series of integers up to an endpoint, it can also produce a series between two points; a third option gives you a step size:

```
>>> list(xrange(1, 6, 2))
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: @Martijin thank you very much. And if I want that xrange, always without 0, is random in 1,100 but the maximum value multiplyed a number like 0,7 is <= the minimum value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking; if you want to limit the range, then just pass calculated values to the `xrange()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just specify another argument:

```
random.sample(xrange(1, y), z)
                     ^
```

Notice the `1`. This is the **start** argument, meaning that `0` is not included here.

Example:

```
>>> list(xrange(1, 10))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```